# Varnish 6.x — stale-if-error implementation

Tags: varnish

I was investigating if varnish can support Stale content as described in [RFC 5861](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5861).
To achieve this `stale-while-revalidate` and `stale-if-error` [cache directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#extension_cache-control_directives) I found a sample implementation for varnish [v4](https://github.com/fgsch/vcl-snippets/blob/master/v4/stale-if-error.vcl) and [v5](https://github.com/fgsch/vcl-snippets/blob/master/v5/stale-if-error.vcl).

But two there are two issues with the implementation:

- First: It was reported to interfere with the native `stale-while-revalidate` (`grace`) capabilities, see [issue](https://github.com/fgsch/vcl-snippets/issues/1)
- Second: There is no sample for varnish v6.

To address the v6 issue, where `return(miss)` was removed from `vcl_hit{}`, I tried the migration suggested in [upgrading-guide](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.5/whats-new/upgrading-6.2.html#vcl):

```
sub try_stale_if_error {
    if (obj.ttl < 0s && obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
        if (req.restarts == 0) {
            set req.http.sie-enabled = true;
            return (restart);
        } else {
            set req.http.sie-abandon = true;
            return (deliver);
        }
    }
}
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts > 0 && req.http.sie-enabled) {
      set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }
}
```

It kinda worked, but is merely more than the build in `grace`/`stale-while-revialidate` as far as I can see.

Would it be possible to implement this feature correctly in a way that `stale-while-revalidate` (`obj.grace`) and `stale-if-error` (maybe use `obj.keep`) can work at the same time in a way, the specification says it should?

Also noteworthy: A `vmod stale` exists for the commercial offering named ["Varnish Cache Plus"](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/stale/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real solution to implement both `stale-if-error` and `stale-while-revalidate` is by using `vmod_stale` in *Varnish Enterprise*.

Here's a `stale-while-revalidate` implementation in regular VCL, but it doesn't have the flexibility to set `stale-while-revalidate` via the `Cache-Control` header:

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

backend default {
    .host="localhost";
    .port="8080";
    .probe={
        .url="/";
    }
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        set req.grace = 10s;
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.sie = std.integer(regsub(beresp.http.Cache-Control,"^.*stale-if-error=([0-9]+).*$","\1"),0);        
    set beresp.grace = std.duration(beresp.http.sie + "s",beresp.grace);
}
```

This example sets grace to whatever the value of `Cache-Control: stale-if-error=...` is. In `vcl_recv` we can limit this value if the server is healthy, but the grace value is hardcoded and cannot come from `Cache-Control: stale-while-revalidate=...`.

`beresp.keep` won't work in this case, because it is only used to keep the object around for synchronous revalidation, whereas grace can be used to serve stale data.

The reason why we developed `vmod_stale` is to re-arm objects and set new TTL, grace & keep values. By initially setting the keep value to an very high number, we ensure that the object is kept around, and `vmod_stale` can then re-arm it.

Your options are to either use my poor man's `stale-if-error` implementation, or upgrade to *Varnish Enterprise*.

#### Sidenote about Varnish Enterprise

One easy way to try out *Varnish Enterprise* without upfront licensing payments, if you’re interested, is to spin up an instance on cloud infrastructure:

- [Varnish Enterprise on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Varnish-Software-Inc-Varnish-Enterprise-6-Ubuntu/prodview-atq2qasjkejio)
- [Varnish Enterprise on Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/varnish.varnish-enterprise)
- [Varnish Enterprise on GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/varnish-public/varnish-enterprise-6-payg-ubuntu)